# Why is the Page_Load event firing when I want to load another page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, pageload

Very new to ASP, and I have what feels like a very basic question.  I have the following code in my default.aspx.cs file:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //Get one day ago
            DateTime oneDayAgo = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().AddDays(-1);
            String strOneDayAgo = oneDayAgo.ToString();

            //Declare the query string
            String queryString = "Select * from Computers Where whenCreated >= '" + strOneDayAgo + "' ORDER BY whenCreated DESC";

            //Show the query being used to the user
            lblQueryUsed.Text = queryString;

            // Run the query and bind the resulting DataSet to the GridView control.
            DataSet ds = GetData(queryString);
            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

All of that works very nicely, but the problem is when a user clicks a link on that page to go to another page called Reports.aspx, that same Page_Load event fires, and all of the controls (lblQueryUsed, GridView1) are set to NULL for some reason, and I get an exception.

Why is the Page_Load event for default.aspx loading when I want to load Reports.aspx? Why are the controls null?

Thanks a lot for the help.

**EDIT:Here is the full code of that page, what else do you need?**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Sorter;
using System.Data;

namespace AD_watcher_web_app
{
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //Get one day ago
            DateTime oneDayAgo = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().AddDays(-1);
            String strOneDayAgo = oneDayAgo.ToString();

            //Declare the query string
            String queryString = "Select * from Computers Where whenCreated >= '" + strOneDayAgo + "' ORDER BY whenCreated DESC";

            //Show the query being used to the user
            lblQueryUsed.Text = queryString;

            // Run the query and bind the resulting DataSet to the GridView control.
            DataSet ds = GetData(queryString);
            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Label1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Populate the labels
        lblCompCount.Text = GridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();
        lblTimeRun.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString();
    }

    ///////////////////////METHODS///////////////////////

    DataSet GetData(String queryString)
    {
        // Set the connection string
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder conBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        conBuilder.DataSource = "dbsql01dev.llnl.gov";
        conBuilder.InitialCatalog = "XloadDB";
        conBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;

        String connectionString = conBuilder.ConnectionString;

        //Declare a new dataset
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        try
        {
          // Connect to the database and run the query.
          SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);        
          SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);

          // Fill the DataSet.
          adapter.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
          // The connection failed. Display an error message.
            lblExceptions.Text = ex.ToString();
            lblExceptions.Visible = true;
        }
        return ds;
      }
}
}
```

Comment: Is the link a server side link?

Comment: Are the links handled on the server or on the client?  In other words, do you have a handler for their click events on the server and you do a `Response.Redirect`, or are these simple hyperlinks?

Comment: Please paste the relevant pieces of the aspx

Comment: If link causes post backs then your page will load again.

Comment: My link looks like this, and is on the Site.Master: <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>

Answer (score 8):

For server side controls to work, the page needs to reload before the control events fire.

This is part of the [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

This behaviour will also occur on server side links - once a postback occurs, the page reloads and `page_load` fires.

To avoid this, make your links into pure client side links.

So, no `runat="server"`, but proper HTML `<a href="">link</a>` links.

Comment: I am afraid the OP is not posting the full code and he's doing something else. There's no reason why these controls are set to null on Page_Load even if he's doing Response.Redirect and not checking IsPostback.

Comment: So here is the ASP that makes up the menu bar on my Site.Master:
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Reports.aspx" Text="Reports" />
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>

Comment: @Icarus - This is still a server side control - `<asp:Menu>`. @Dbloom - this is how webforms work. When you use a server side control, a postback occurs and `page_load` runs. That's why `IsPostBack` exists.

Comment: But I have the statement if (!IsPostBack), and Postback is showing as False, so doesn't that mean a postback is not occurring? Sorry, the Page lifecycle is still murky to me.

Comment: I've been playing around with trying to make the links client side, but the line <head runat="server"> is at the top of my Site.Master, so does that mean everything enclosed in the <head> tag will be server side?

Comment: @Dbloom - There is no reason for the `head` element to be server side. That is, unless you are manipulating the contents on the server side.

Comment: I added all of the controls in the designer, and it seems to make all of them server side. As I look at the asp markup, all of the controls and ASP Content tags like <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"> are all server side.  I feel like I am missing something very basic here :(

Comment: OK, I deleted my Reports.aspx page and added a new page.  It now works.  Thanks for all the help, I know more than before, but not sure what I did to fix this, besides getting rid of the Inherits from Default that was there before...